# Edit word file in DB, without re upload it after

Tags: c#, ms-word

I am wondering if it is possible to edit a word file stored in a DB ( as blob) without re upload it after.

I, at the moment, open my file with an aspx page(I am in a silverlight application), so I register the file in the desktop, and then, re register it in databse.

And that is a lot of work, if there is a lot of file that must be edited.

So, I found [Editing Word files stored in a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3455663), but this still require to upload it.

Can't I open the document with Interop, and then when I register, and when I save the document, then, just submit the changes and the document in the database will be the edited one?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is possible. Once your file is a BLOB in the database, it can only be read (and written) as a whole. So you cannot update parts of a BLOB, which is what you need in your scenario.

I think technically it should be possible to have Word write your file directly to a database on saving. The bytes are written to a file system or cloud repository when you save in Word, writing to a database shouldn't be too difficult. However, this is not a feature of Word that I know of (and it doesn't really help with your question because Word would still have to download your file and write it as a whole).